# How to update the value of DatetimeIndex of a single row in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

In a python pandas DataFrame, I would like to update the value of the index in a single row (preferably in-place as the DataFrame is quite large).

The index is DatetimeIndex and the DataFrame may contain several columns.

For instance:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: pd.DataFrame({'DATA': [1,2,3]},
                      index=[pd.Timestamp(2011,10,01,00,00,00),
                             pd.Timestamp(2011,10,01,02,00,00),
                             pd.Timestamp(2011,10,01,03,00,00)])
Out[5]: 
                     DATA
2011-10-01 00:00:00     1
2011-10-01 02:00:00     2
2011-10-01 03:00:00     3
```

The desired output is:

```
                     DATA
2011-10-01 01:00:00     1   <---- Index changed !!!
2011-10-01 02:00:00     2
2011-10-01 03:00:00     3
```

Is there a simple (and cheap) way to do this for large DataFrames ?

Assuming the location of the sample is known (for instance it is the nth row the needs to be changed) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution with [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html), but first need convert [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html):

```
df.index = df.index
             .to_series()
             .replace({pd.Timestamp('2011-10-01'): pd.Timestamp('2011-10-01 01:00:00')})
print (df)
                     DATA
2011-10-01 01:00:00     1
2011-10-01 02:00:00     2
2011-10-01 03:00:00     3
```

Another solution with [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#new-index-methods) (new in `0.19.0`):

```
df.index = df.index.where(df.index != pd.Timestamp('2011-10-01'),
                          [pd.Timestamp('2011-10-01 01:00:00')])

print (df)
                     DATA
2011-10-01 01:00:00     1
2011-10-01 02:00:00     2
2011-10-01 03:00:00     3
```

Solution with appending new row and remove old one by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.loc[pd.Timestamp('2011-10-01 01:00:00')] = df.loc['2011-10-01 00:00:00', 'DATA']
df.drop(pd.Timestamp('2011-10-01 00:00:00'), inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print (df)
                     DATA
2011-10-01 01:00:00     1
2011-10-01 02:00:00     2
2011-10-01 03:00:00     3
```

Another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40341544/2901002) if need replace by value not by position:

```
df.index.set_value(df.index, pd.Timestamp(2011,10,1,0,0,0), pd.Timestamp(2011,10,1,1,0,0))
print (df)
                     DATA
2011-10-01 01:00:00     1
2011-10-01 02:00:00     2
2011-10-01 03:00:00     3
```

Last solution with converting `index` to `numpy array` from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340787/how-to-update-the-value-of-datetimeindex-of-a-single-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe#comment67967118_40341089):

```
i = 0
df.index.values[i] = pd.Timestamp('2011-10-01 01:00:00')
print (df)          
                     DATA
2011-10-01 01:00:00     1
2011-10-01 02:00:00     2
2011-10-01 03:00:00     3
```

Comment: These are working indeed but they seem to perform some kind of search and they re-assign the whole index. I know the index of the row to be changed, so can I use this information to avoid searching through a really big index vector ?

Comment: I add another solution, please check it.

Comment: How about this one ? df.index.values[i] = pd.Timestamp('2011-10-01 01:00:00') ? It works for me but I don't know if it has any side effects. If you don't think so, please add it to your answer.

Comment: I test it, please give me a time.

Comment: It is indeed faster but it still includes a search somehow. A search is redundant if I know the exact position. (this is about the  df.set_value() method).

Comment: thank you for accepting! I add your solution to answer, it is really interesting.

Answer (score 2):

A Fast way would be a direct lookup if you already are aware of the index to be operated upon and then you can set it's value accordingly with the help of [`Index.set_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.set_value.html#pandas.Index.set_value):

```
df.index.set_value(df.index, df.index[0], pd.Timestamp(2011,10,1,1,0,0))
#                  <-index-> <-row num->  <---value to be inserted--->
```

This is an inplace operation, so you don't need to assign back the result to itself.

Comment: Is there a better documentation for this method "Index.set_value" than the one on the pandas docs page ? All what is says: use this if you know what you're doing !!! Is it performing a binary search so it needs a sorted array for example ?

Comment: I've commented to provide further explanation. I Know the doc-page lacks an illustration regarding it's usage. But if you go through answers regarding `DF.set_value`, you would fairly get an idea as it works very similar to that.